# How do I use C++ to acquire image from frame grabber?

Tags: c++, image, matrix-vision

I would like to know how is it possible to use a free C++ program to acquire image from a matrix vision frame grabber. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.matrix-vision.com/support/hardwareinfo.php?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of your frame grabber card. Look for "SDK" (software development kit). Maybe your operating system has its own interface which you can use if the "driver" has been installed. I would guess you have to do both things: Install all drivers and use some special library as part of the SDK that is provided with this product.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK (hopefully a dll with some exported functions for your help) usually comes by installing the grabber's drivers.Since it is a graphic card my guess would be that it would be found among the media devices which you can retrieve.

The SDK is stand alone and therefore can be used by your code in c++